# Вставить данные из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: php, mysql

Как мне вставить данные из одной таблицы в другую, но при этом еще добавить несколько полей? Пробую так

```
$th_close = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("SELECT * FROM `ordersbuy` WHERE status = 1");
    $th_array = array();
    while ($row = $th_close->fetch_assoc()) {
        $th_array[] = $row;

    $closeord = time(); 
    $res = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("INSERT INTO `trade_history`(`ID_prod`, `ID_poc`, `Val`, `Prod`, `Type`, `Price`, `Amount`, `Total`, `TimeCreateOrder`, `TimeCloseOrder`) VALUES (300,299,'".$row['Val']."','".$row['Prod']."','".$row['Type']."','".$row['price']."','".$row['amount']."','".$row['total']."','".$row['ordtime']."',$closeord)");
    }
```

Но если записей в таблице ordersbuy больше 1, то соотвественно данный запрос не работает.

Comment: одним запросом: `insert into trade(...) select 300, 299, val, prod, ..., now() from ordersbuy ...`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Mike а будет работать запрос, если значений 300 и 299 в таблице ordersbuy  нет?

Comment: @Bertly разумеется, запрос может возвращать константы. Вы собственно сначала просто select с нужной структурой сделайте и посмотрите устраивают ли вас данные. А потом к нему insert допишите

Comment: @Mike все равно запрос не работает, если в таблице ordersbuy больше 1 записи с полем статус=1

Comment: Что значит "не работает" ? Он должен либо работать, либо давать ошибку. Может у вас нарушение какого нибудь уникального ключа проиосходит

Comment: @Mike в начале скрипта дописал ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);  и никаких ошибок не выводит

Comment: в логах тоже ничего

Comment: Так он сам и не выведет, если вы mysqli должным образом не настроили. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting  А так же https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Mike вот что выводит, Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in /home//public_html/update.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/update.php(8): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `tr...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/public_html/update.php on line 8

Comment: так решайте проблему. как я и подозревал нарушение уникального ключа. Как будто у вас нет автоинкремента или вы явно задали значение для id в запросе

Comment: @Mike а как можно исключить из выборки поля из таблицы ordersbuy с полем orderid, которое уже было вставлено в прошлом?

Comment: `where not exists(...)`